# The php files I move from localhost to webhost are not working properly

Tags: apache, web-hosting, webmin

I moved my project from localhost to web host.But some codes dont run without error like "header php code","src code ignore space" ...I use webmin panel and last upgraded Apache Server.I guess issue about apache server.I need advice for use webmin,linux and apache server 
Example:"header('location: http://localhost/stock2/dashboard.php'); " This code doesnt run in webhost

Comment: obviously, things like header('location: http:// **localhost** will not work

Comment: You r right but its just example.